# Questions about the relation between convergence in distribution and convergence in probability

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I have two sequences of random variables $\{ X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n \}$. I know that
$X_n \to^d D, Y_n \to^d D$. Can I conclude that $X_n - Y_n \to^p 0$?

If I cannot, what other conditions do I need for the conclusion to hold? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. Take $Z_n$ i.i.d Then $Z_n \Rightarrow Z_{\infty} =_d Z_1$. Set $Z_{2n} = X_{n}$ and $Z_{2n+1} = Y_n$. Clearly there is no convergence in probability of $X_n-Y_n$. Another issue is convergence in probability needs all your random variables to be defined on the same probability space, which just from convergence in distribution is not true in general. But even if they are on same probability space, you still cannot conclude as the counter-example shows.

Comment: Hi, but I thought that there are some laws about proving that if covergence in distirbution is equal to a point, and under this condition, convergecen in probability and convergence in distirbution are identical. Are there any methods I can use to prove the convergence in distribution can lead to convergence in probability? Thanks

Comment: @Neyman Convergence in distribution to a constant is equivalent to convergence in probability.

Comment: Hi, so can I interpret it as a necessary and sufficient condition (iff condition) to ensure a random variable sequence for convergence in probability? Thanks.

Comment: @Neyman If it's to a constant, yes. Hence oftentimes we just write $X_n \Rightarrow c$ to mean $X_n \to c$ in probability because weak convergence and convergence in probability to a constant are the same. If it's not to a constant, you can't say much...unless you have some extra hypotheses.

Comment: Thank u. I will try to think more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Convergence in distribution is called weak convergence because all that matters is the frequency of values an RV takes. That says nothing about how a variable is correlated with another. For example, let X be uniform on $[0,1]$ and Y=1-X. They are identical in distribution, yet X cannot in general be expected to be close to Y.

Comment: Hi, but I thought that there are some laws about proving that if covergence in distirbution is equal to a point, and under this condition, convergecen in probability and convergence in distirbution are identical. Are there any methods I can use to prove the convergence in distribution can lead to convergence in probability? Thanks.

Comment: You're right. If there is "essentially" one outcome, you don't need to know any more information about the probability space. Other than this case, you need to know how the variables correlate to get convergence in probability. Here is a list of implications that might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_4